# c++ - offsetof function, why is it possible to pass just the member name

Tags: c++

when I define a struct like this:

```
struct abc{
 int member1;
 int arr_member1;
 std::vector<int> mVector;
}
```

and want to make an `arr_member` variable, I'd have to do this:

```
abc x;
x.member1=3;
x.arr_member1= ...

//some more code
```

but I can't do something like this:

```
arr_member1 a = //some code
```

where a is supposed to be a variable that is an int array of 5 elements.

but, how can I do this for the offsetof() function:

```
offsetof(abc, arr_member1)
```

I can understand that `abc` refers to a type which is a struct, but what is the `arr_member` technically? What is it called? A pointer, a type, a member type? What does this macro expand to and how does the compiler compile this?

What I meant was, that `arr_member` is not a string or a keyword, it's not any data type defined by the language nor a class, so how is the compiler figuring out it's not just some random thing?

If possible, please mention how a particular macro could possibly be implemented by a compiler?

Comment: `arr_member1 a` doesn't make any sense, as `arr_member1` does not name a type. What are you really trying to achieve, and what does `offsetof` have to do with it?

Comment: are you sure you aren't looking for something like `decltype`?

Comment: `arr_member` is called "undeclared identifier", as no such name is ever declared in the code shown.

Comment: `offsetof` cannot be implemented in c++ (it's *magic*, the standard simply says what it should do). If you're asking how a particular compiler implements it, then clarify the question, and add the appropriate tag.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik , I mean  `arr_member` is not a string, and not a keyword so how is the compiler figuring out it is a member of the struct?

Comment: `arr_member` is not a member of any struct in the code shown. If you mean `arr_member1`, then it's a data member of struct `abc` because the definition of struct `abc` declares it to be member of that struct.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik , I did mean arr_member1 , sorry for the typo

Comment: @IgorTandetnik , what is `arr_member1` called? It's not any data type recognized by c++, and not a string, how is c++ identifying that it's a `supposed-to-be-recognized-as-something-special` thing and not just some random stuff in the program?

Comment: `arr_member1` is a named member of `struct abc`.  It's data type is `int`.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your real code / the code you'd like to write and the compiler error

Comment: `arr_member1` is a name. In certain contexts, the name lookup establishes that this name refers to a data member of a struct that in turn is known by the name `abc`. That data member has a type; its type is `int`.

Comment: @idclev463035818 , there's no error, I'm just asking about the language feature

Comment: "offsetof function, why is it possible to pass just the member name" it is not clear what you mean by that. Can you show an example for that?

Comment: well ok I think I know what is your confusion/problem

Comment: I meant this `offsetof(abc, arr_member1) `, why are you being able to pass it when it's nothing known to c++, as you may already know, members of struct cannot directly be accessed, but this produces no errors

Comment: @IgorTandetnik , what you mention about the name lookup process is more satisfying, can you please point to a page in the docs or explain it a bit further? Is this more of a compiler feature rather than a language feature, meaning that the compiler replaces it with whatever appropriate?

Comment: `offsetof` is a macro. It performs some text substitutions using its parameters, which in the end produces a valid code the compiler does understand.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand the distinction. [Name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup) is a process the compiler performs in accordance to the rules specified by the C++ language standard. It is a process by which a use of a given name is matched up with the previous declaration of that name, in order to determine what entity the name refers to in the given context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because offsetof is a macro, inside the macro definition, the field name will be used together with the type you passed in. It looks like this:

```
#define offsetof(st, m) \
    ((size_t)&(((st *)0)->m))
```

source:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof

Comment: It should be noted that this implementation: 1. relies on UB, and 2. is not `constexpr`, unlike the standard one.

Comment: It would be useful to add that this is pseudo-code and not legal C++.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , what is UB?

Comment: @juztcode UB is undefined behaviour. It means youare not allowed to do this. In this case at least the null pointer dereference happening during -> invokes UB. You must not dereference a null pointer. The C++ language doesn’t give you any guarantee what happens at that point. Consequently anything can happen. If you’re lucky, your program crashes. If you’re unlucky it continues, writes garbage to the database and in a month you’ll have to explain to an enraged customer why all his data is corrupted. In its current form this is not a valid answer.

Comment: um.... yes I suppose so, but the answer got pin point to what I wanted to ask, so I marked it as answer, although @idclev answer was also very good , I've suggested the answerer an edit

Comment: The compiler vendor can do tricks like this, because what is undefined behavior to the language can be defined behavior that the compiler vendor can utilize.  Other compiler vendors may implement `offsetof` differently, possibly even by having a compiler internal mechanism like `#define offsetof(st, m) __offsetof(st, m)`

Comment: To be clear, it is just a piece of pseudo code I borrowed from the wiki page to demonstrate the concept. It's not the real implementation.

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand most of your question, but the title:

> offsetof function, why is it possible to pass just the member name

```
offsetof(abc, arr_member1)
```

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof):

> offsetof cannot be implemented in standard C++ and requires compiler support

The reason it cannot be implemented in stadard C++ is because outside of the class `arr_member1` is no entity. Its just the name of the member. The compiler knows the name of the class members, but `arr_memer1` is (outside of the class) nothing you could do anything with. C++ has pointer to member, but `offsetof` does not take a pointer to member as parameter. Its a nasty macro that is not based on a feature of C++, but relies on compilers having access to their own implementation.

Comment: could please tell me how a compiler could possibly implement this?

Comment: If you follow the link in the answer, there are links to 2 different implementations you can look at.

Comment: @cigien , yeah it gives a link to `gcc` and `llvm` implementations but they give something like: `#define offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER) __builtin_offsetof (TYPE, MEMBER)` only which is hardly of any use, unless can we dive deeper somehow?

Comment: Of course, look for the definition of `__builtin_offsetof`, and so on...